# how to encrypt an image name by a small string using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

hi i tried to insert an image link with image name encryption but it gives me a long string `"profiles\October2020\eyJpdiI6InBQWmtcL2dCWGk3UnJ3MG1BcVV2NWJ3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Im43UkVOMzV0Z0hyMmtHRHJUTVM3ZTdaT3hYTXNVVGR5UjRDZE5vU3Z1aTQ9IiwibWFjIjoiZGUzY2Q2NjAzNDRmMDUzYTQzNTU4OGE0MGVlMDNiYWQ1ZWFiNTQ4ZGM2ZjFmZjhmMDU3NDI0Y2U3MGNmODJmYiJ9.jpeg`, is there any other way to give me a small string.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $jdate = Carbon::now();
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $imagee = Crypt::encryptString($image);
        $image->storeAs("public\profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year,$imagee.'.'.$image->extension());
        $request->image = "profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".$imagee.'.'.$image->extension(); 
    }
    $im = $request->image;
    dd($im);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing that? I can't really think of any reason to encrypt the name of an image.

Comment: If you don't need the original data again (decrypt that string) you can use a hash like `md5()` that will give a 32 chars length string or you can even use a slice of that string

Comment: `$imagee = Crypt::encryptString($image);` this line make your string longer

Comment: @Dave yes during adding an image, I store my image in a storage / profiles folder if I store an image with the same name it replaces the 1st image with the 2nd lol

Comment: You certainly do not need to encrypt the name. Use something simple like the date and time and a bit from the `rand` function. If this image is associated with a user ID of some sort use the user ID and a value from `rand`. You're going to check for collisions anyway when you store it (right?).

Comment: @HappyEmotion you are welcome. I wrote that comment before you show us more details in your comment, so I suggest as Dave told you, you can just **add** the timestamp, date and time,  the user ID , or even a random string **to the name of the image**, so you make sure it doesn't conflict with other images names. That will be much simpler than encrypting the image binaries itself.

Comment: Laravel will already give you a random 40 character name if you use `store` instead of `storeAs`

Comment: @Accountantم this method does not work in this code because it will give offset between name of image which stores in folder and name which will insert in db ,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of encrypting the file to get a random string, you could generate a hash.

```php
 $imageName = hash('sha1', $image);
```

Function : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.hash.php

List of algo (so, you can choose the string length) : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.hash-algos.php

You can add a random number if you want the file name to be unique each time

```php
 $imageName = hash('sha1', $image . random_int (100, 1000000));
```

Answer (score -1):

May you try something like this:

```
substr(base64_encode(sha1(mt_rand())), 0, 10)
```

In this example, we have a random string with 10 characters. You can replace the function mt_rand() by the original file name.

Comment: Why would you ever use `base64_encode` if you `substr` it later?

Comment: The encode was more of an aesthetic issue, and then use substr to select the number of characters for the image name.
Why is it wrong?  Why negative? Justify it, please. The problem was simple, just generating a random name for the file.

Comment: I also can't see what's the problem with a base64 encoding.

Comment: SHA-1 is the fastest hashing function; I just used it for that reason.

Comment: If you are talking about collisions (because there is no security issue about using sha1 here) have a look to. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/is-it-fair-to-assume-that-sha1-collisions-wont-occur-on-a-set-of-100k-stringspa

Comment: The op is also creating a folder using the date (mounth + year), and i am pretty sure that he won't store more than 100k files in one folder per mounth. By the way, have fun to find a FS that can store more than 100k files in a directory.